# Getting error android resource linking failed in android manifest file while trying to integrate facebook login

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest, facebook-authentication

I am Integrating facebook login into my app for the first time but I am Getting error while trying to integrate facebook login with my flutter app, i have followed all necessary steps for facebook login integration but getting errors in android manifest file.
This is my android manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devex.giraffe">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="Giraffe"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDJBfBCW5So5ewm6TF0u8FO9sEFvm-YpU0"/>

            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <queries>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

and these errors i am getting.

```
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     D:\Flutter Company projects\giraffe_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:48:9-50:48: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.devex.giraffe:string/app_name) not found.

     D:\Flutter Company projects\giraffe_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:58:17-75: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_login_protocol_scheme (aka com.devex.giraffe:string/fb_login_protocol_scheme) not found.
```

Comment: Please add your strings.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

1. See if you have **strings.xml** file at Project/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml (create file if it doesn't exist)
2. If you have **strings.xml** then according to latest code its content should be like

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Your app name Here</string>
        <string name="facebook_app_id">your id Here</string>
        <string name="facebook_client_token">FB Client Token Here</string>
        <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">FB Login Protocol scheme Here</string>
    </resources>
   ```

- app name = simply name of your app
- Facebook id = you can find in upper left corner of your screen in FB
  Console
- FB Client Token = you can find that in console/ Dashboard, navigate
  to Settings > Advanced > Security > Client token.
- FB Login Prototcol Scheme = simpli fb + Facebook id e.g. (fb0000000000000000)

on many places I found people recommending including or decluding a specific thing but in my case I gave them all

Comment: it's important to notice that the `strings.xml` location matters. it should be placed inside the `/values` directory, forming `/values/strings.xml` otherwise it will not be located